# Am I trapped in Velika?

Tags: tera

I am at the part of the tutorial where I am supposed to leave Velika, but I don't have money to pay for the pegasus - slightly over 10 silvers.

I took the tutorial armor crafting quest and spent all my money on materials which I have used up crafting the training armor. That training armor is not sellable and I ran out of cash because I could make enough of them to turn in for the quest.

Am I stuck now? Is there another way (hopefully repeatable) to make money in Velika? Or do I have to sell the literal clothes off my character's back to get out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to take the pegasus, you can also leave Velika by foot or with your horse, just check your map and look for the city doors.

Answer (score 0):

There's three things that come to mind that you can do in this situation:

1. The most time consuming is to leave Velika on foot via one of the city doors.
2. If you have friends that play the game or don't mind posting in global chat, you could ask if someone could spare the bit of silver it costs to travel. Some high level out there may be nice and help you out (you may even get a nice surprise and get some extra stuff).
3. Like you already mentioned, literally sell any gear you have remaining on your character that is sellable. I don't recommend this though.